# Multi-OS text-based database with an engine for Python and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, database, json, wxpython

This is probably a far fetch, but maybe someone knows a good solution for it.

**Introduction**

I'm currently making an application in Python with the new wxPython 2.9, which has the new `html2` library, which will inherit the native browser of each OS (Safari/IE/Firefox/Konquerer/~), which is really great.

**Goal/Purpose**

What I'm currently aiming for is to process large chunks of data and analyze it super fast with Python (currently about 110.000 entries, turning out in about 1.500.000 to 2.250.000 results in a dictionary). This works very fast and is also dynamic, so it will only do that first big fetch once (takes about 2-4 seconds only) and afterwards just keeps listening if new data gets created on the disc.

So far, so good. Now with the new wxPython `html2` library I'm making the new GUI. It's mainly made to display pages, so what I have made now is a model in a `/html/` folder (with HTML/CSS/jQuery) and it will dynamically look for a JSON files (jQuery fetching), which is practically a complete dump of the massive dictionaries that the Python script is making in the background (daemon) in a parallel thread.

JavaScript doesn't seem to have issues with reading a big JSON file and because everything is (and stays) local it doesn't really incur slowness or anything. Also the CPU and memory usage is very low.

**Conclusion**

But here comes the bottleneck. From the JavaScript point of view, the handling of the big JSON file is not really a joyride. I have todo a lot of searching and matching for all the data I need to get, and also creates a lot of redundant re-looping through the same big chunks of entries.

**Question**

I'm wondering if there is any kind of "engine" that is implemented for both Python and JavaScript that can handle jSON files, or maybe other text-based files as a database. Meaning you can really have a MySQL-like structure (not meant by full extend of course), where you at least can define a table structure which hold the data and you do reads/write/updates on methodically.

The app I'm currently developing is multi-OS based (at least Ubuntu, OS X and Windows XP+). I also really don't want to create more clutter than using wxPython (for distribution/dependency sakes) to use an extension database (like I could run a MySQL server on localhost), so purely keep it inside my Python distro's folder. This is also to prevent writing massive code (checks) checking if the user has already got servers/databases in use that might collide with what my app I would then install.

---

***Final Notes***

I'm kind of aiming to build some kind of API myself too for future projects to make this way of development standard for my Python scripts that need a GUI. Now that wxPython can more easily embrace the modern browser technologies; there seems to be no limit anymore to building super fast, dynamic and responsive graphical Python apps.

Comment: This question is in bad need of editing. What's your actual problem? That you're processing a lot of JSON in the browser? Then process *less* JSON, don't just dump your entire application state every time. Given your self-answer it kind of seems like you're fishing for rep by going "hey I invented the concept of an AJAX/JSON API". (Which, really, you didn't, and is the obvious choice here if you're communicating with a backend server anyway.)

Comment: Seriously? What a spiteful comment.. "Fishing for rep"? Based on your reputation it seriously seems you are one of those. I just came around to see that approach and thought to post it as a solution. There's nothing wrong with my question; you just want to mock me?.. Please just stay away if you have nothing useful to say. I don't care if your reputation is high or if you are a king. I'm offended.. People should stop with doing assumption after assumption, creating their own disillusions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just stick the data into a SQLite database and then have both Python and Javascript hit that? See also [Convert JSON to SQLite in Python - How to map json keys to database columns properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811783/convert-json-to-sqlite-in-python-how-to-map-json-keys-to-database-columns-prop)

Sqlite is included with in all modern versions of Python. You'll have to check out the SQLite website for its limitations

Comment: The issue stays that JavaScript can't read/write anything in the browser, as it uses the native implementation. I'm currently trying to run a CGI server, but I'm getting permissions errors. Very troublesome. I would like to server a CGIHTTPServer to let Python be a portal for jQuery to do AJAX calls and fetch SQLite data.

Comment: Check my own answer. I wonder what feedback (tips/advice) you have on it.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of got something figured out, through running a CGI HTTP server and letting Python in there fetch SQLite queries for JavaScript's AJAX calls. Here's a small demo (only tested on OS X):

***Folder structure***

```
main.py
cgi/index.py
data/
html/index.html
html/scripts/jquery.js
html/scripts/main.js
html/styles/main.css
```

**Python server (main.py)**

```
### CGI Server ###
import CGIHTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer

class Handler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ['/cgi']

    # Mute the messages in the shell
    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        return

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 61350), Handler)
#httpd.serve_forever()
thread = threading.Thread(name='CGIHTTPServer', target=httpd.serve_forever)
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()

#### TEST SQLLite ####
# Make the database file if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists('data/sqlite.db'):
    db_file = open('data/sqlite.db', 'w')
    db_file.write('')
    db_file.close()
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('data/sqlite.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE info(id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(75), folder_name VARCHAR(75))')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO info VALUES(null, "something1", "something1_name")')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO info VALUES(null, "something2", "something1_name")')
conn.commit()
```

**Python SQLite processor (cgi/index.py) (demo is purely for SELECT, needs more dynamic)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import json
import sqlite3
print 'Content-Type: text/json\n\n'

### Fetch GET-data ###
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
obj = {}

### SQLite fetching ###
query = form.getvalue('query', 'ERROR')
output = ''

if query == 'ERROR':
    output = 'WARNING! No query was given!'
else:
    # WARNING: The path probably needs `../data/sqlite.db` if PYTHONPATH is not defined
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data/sqlite.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    # TODO: Add functionality/detect if it's a SELECT, INSERT/UPDATE (then we need to conn.commit() )
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    if len(result) > 0:
        output = []

        for row in result:
            buff = []

            for entry in row:
                buff.append(entry)

            output.append(buff)
    else:
        output = 'WARNING! No results found'

obj = output

### Return the data in jSON (map) format for JavaScript
print json.dumps(obj)
```

**JavaScript (html/scripts/main.js)**

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function() {
    // JSON data read test
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM test';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:61350/cgi/index.py?query=' + query,
        success: function(data) {
            lg(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            lg('Something went wrong while fetching the query.');
        }
    });
});
```

And that wraps it up. The console output in the browser is;

```
[
    [1, "something1", "something1_name"],
    [2, "something2", "something2_name"]
]
```

With this methodology you could let Python and JavaScript read/write in the same database, while Python keeps doing its system tasks (daemon) and update the database entries, whilst JavaScript can keep checking for new data.

This method could probably also add room for listeners and other means of communication between the both.

The `main.py` will instantly stop running because of the daemon. This is because of my wxPython script after it that keeps the daemon (server) alive until the application stops. If someone else wants to use this code for the future; just make sure the server-code runs after the SQLite initiation and unquote `httpd.serve_forever()` to keep it running.