# Creating a table from BLS labor statistics using JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Python, but have been working on a problem for quite some time.  The BLS website uses JSON inter-change format.  I've been able to process data calls to make an output table file.  However, rather than print line by line to an outfile, I'd prefer to build a table that I can sort rows by the seriesID (smallest to largest) and sort the date entries by observation (smallest to largest).  One motivation for doing this is that it is conceivable that the order of the observations in the list may not line up over all the series (more likely the case with other BLS data series). I'd also like to migrate this to a dynamic web page for reporting the latest employment statistics.  I have my current working code below.

```
#JSON call to //api.bls.gov/ retrieve and print "National Employment by Major Industry"

import requests
import json
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({"seriesid":        ['CES0000000001','CES1000000001','CES2000000001','CES3000000001','CES4000000001','CES5000000001','CES5500000001','CES6000000001','CES6500000001','CES7000000001','CES8000000001','CES9091000001','CES9092000001','CES9093000001'],"startyear":"2012", "endyear":"2012"})
p = requests.post('http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/', data=data, headers=headers)
print p.url
print p.content
json_data = json.loads(p.text)
d_results = json_data['Results']  #Dictionary: seriesID: str, data: list of data by date
l_series = d_results['series']    #List of Dictionaries

makeheader = 'True'
f=open('outfile.csv','w')
for lst in sorted(l_series):
    tmp = lst                   #Dictionary: seriesID: str, data: list of data observation dictionaries
#    type(tmp)
    tmpp = tmp['data']          #List of data observation dictionaries
    if makeheader == 'True':
        for ent in tmp['data']:
            f.write( ',' + ent['year'] + ":" + ent['period'] ),  #create observation marker as YYYY:MM
        makeheader = 'False'
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(tmp['seriesID'] ),
    for ent in tmp['data']:
        f.write(',' + ent['value'] ),
f.close
```

I've thought about making lists of seriesID's and observations that are sortable.  I could then possibly use those list to pull data from the json list of dictionaries, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to locate the proper dictionary in the list.  The first part of that looks like the following:

```
# continuation...
s1 = []                  # Get and sort series IDs
for ent in l_series:
    s1.append(ent['seriesID'])
s1.sort()

d1 = []                  # Get and sort observations (currently collected as tubles)
for ent in l_series[0]['data']:
    d1.append( (ent['year'] + ":" + ent['period'] , ent['year'] , ent['period']) )
d1.sort()
```

So, I was hoping to get some guidance on strategies for proceeding from this group.  Any thought will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend loading the BLS data directly into a relational database such as SQLite where the relationship is the "date." I didn't look too hard, but this should work:
[Convert JSON to SQLite in Python - How to map json keys to database columns properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811783/convert-json-to-sqlite-in-python-how-to-map-json-keys-to-database-columns-prop)

Then you can execute a SQL join query if you want to "line up" all the series data between 2 different sources (e.g. unemployment and inflation). For example:

```
SELECT unemployment.*,inflation.* FROM unemployment 
INNER JOIN inflation ON unemployment.date = inflation.date;
```

The issue with the sorting approach is that you'll have to solve several problems that are already solved by a relational database such as "what to do when the row is in table A, but not B" or "you have a duplicate entry in table A" etc.