# Insert dictionary into SQLlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I want to insert data from a dictionary into a sqlite table, I am using slqalchemy to do that, the keys in the dictionary and the column names are the same, and I want to insert the values into the same column name in the table. So this is my code:

```
#This is the class where I create a table from with sqlalchemy, and I want to
#insert my data into.
#I didn't write the __init__ for simplicity
class Sizecurve(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'sizecurve'
     XS = Column(String(5))
     S = Column(String(5))
     M = Column(String(5))
     L = Column(String(5))
     XL = Column(String(5))
     XXL = Column(String(5))

o = Mapping()   #This creates an object which is actually a dictionary
for eachitem in myitems:
    # Here I populate the dictionary with keys from another list
    # This gives me a dictionary looking like this: o={'S':None, 'M':None, 'L':None}
    o[eachitem] = None
for eachsize in mysizes:
    # Here I assign values to each key of the dictionary, if a value exists if not just None
    # product_row is a class and size and stock are its attributes
    if(product_row.size in o):
        o[product_row.size] = product_row.stock
    # I put the final object into a list
        simplelist.append(o)
```

Now I want to put each the values from the dictionaries saved in simplelist into the right column in the sizecurve table. But I am stuck I don't know how to do that? So for example I have an object like this:

```
o= {'S':4, 'M':2, 'L':1}
```

And I want to see for the row for column S value 4, column M value 2 etc.

Comment: you can convert it to json , then encode it and make string from that , then save the string to database , or you can have enough columns to save each parameter in its special column

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible (though aren't you missing primary keys/foreign keys on this table?).

```
session.add(Sizecurve(**o))
session.commit()
```

That should insert the row.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements

EDIT: On second read it seems like you are trying to insert all those values into one column? If so, I would make use of pickle.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html

If performance is an issue (pickle is pretty fast, but if your doing 10000 reads per second it'll be the bottleneck), you should either redesign the table or use a database like PostgreSQL that supports JSON objects.

Comment: I tried the Sizecurve.insert() but I get an error: AttributeError: type object 'Sizecurve' has no attribute 'insert', which I know it makes sense, because there is no method insert defined in Sizecurve. Do I need to create it myself?

Comment: This will work, as long as the key names are the same as the column names. There's a way to make the classes implemented with Base behave the original way, but I'm drawing a blank right now.

Answer (score -1):

I have found this answer to a similar question, though this is about reading the data from a json file, so now I am working on understanding the code and also changing my data type to json so that I can insert them in the right place.
[Convert JSON to SQLite in Python - How to map json keys to database columns properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811783/convert-json-to-sqlite-in-python-how-to-map-json-keys-to-database-columns-prop)