# Efficient way to convert long JSON keys to SQLite database

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I have a complicated JSON file with many parameters and I need to convert it into a SQLite database.

Here is my example chunk of data:

```
{"hostname": "DESKTOP-A5C21U7", "ts": 1494334366.1905415, "parameters":
[{"label": "T16", "name": "T16", "unit": "K", "value": 78.84589895546188}, 
{"label": "PID Mode", "name": "pid_mode", "unit": "", "value": "off"}, 
 {"label": "IDN", "name": "IDN", "unit": "", "value": 
 {"vendor": null, "model": "dummy", "serial": null, "firmware": null}}, 
 {"label": "PID Mode", "name": "pid_ramp", "unit": "", "value": "off"}, 
 {"label": "PID heater range", "name": "pid_range", "unit": "mA", "value": 0.316},
 {"label": "Status", "name": "status", "unit": "", "value": "Error"}, 
 {"label": "PID temperature setpoint", "name": "pid_setpoint", "unit": "K", "value": 0.0},
 {"label": "PID ramp rate", "name": "pid_rate", "unit": "K/min", "value": 0.0},
 {"label": "Current action", "name": "action", "unit": "", "value": "Idle"},
 {"label": "T6", "name": "T6", "unit": "K", "value": 180.17461269853666}]}
```

I have tried to solve it in a similar as was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811783/convert-json-to-sqlite-in-python-how-to-map-json-keys-to-database-columns-prop) but it doesn't map the table correctly and I keep getting SQL errors.

What is a good and simple way to order long strings and dictionary values into SQL databases?

I have just started SQLite and pretty new in python as well.

Thanks!

Comment: "How do I create a SQL database?" (especially without specifying which database software you want to use) is far too broad a question.

Comment: sorry it was SQLite @chepner

Comment: What have you accomplished so far? Show us your code and your error messages so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

you could use below code to retrieve all the data one by one , and then insert into your DB table .code tested under python 3.6

```
jsonobject = json.dumps(data)

jsonobjectToString = json.loads(jsonobject)


for resp in jsonobjectToString["parameters"]:
    print (resp["label"])
    print (resp["name"])
    print (resp["unit"])
    print (resp["value"])
```

============================
      T16
      K
      78.84589895546188
      PID Mode
      pid_mode

```
  off
  IDN
  IDN
```