# Writing json data as row to SQL database with python

Tags: python, sql, json

I have a python app communicating with a PostgresSQL database via `psycopg2`, and the app is receiving data as json. e.g.:

```
'{"name":"brian","height":24,"gpslat":-0.0543,"foo":"bar"}'
```

The json keys (`['name', 'height', 'gpslat', 'foo']`) match the column names in a table in the database. I'm wondering what's the best way to construct SQL queries to translate the json data as simply a new row in the SQL table.

I could loop through the json as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812069), but isn't it inefficient to run `cursor.execute()` for every key in the json? Is there a way of constructing an SQL command which intelligently assigns the entries to the columns specified?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you are asking, but maybe you are looking for `cursor.executemany(...)`?